# Using an IntentService to do Prioritized Networking

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent, priority-queue

I've been wondering if it is possible to use an `IntentService` to do some networking while keeping the queue of pending intents prioritized. My goal to be able to download some images in the background, add more if needed (send another `Intent`) and be able to reset the queue if necessary (preferably using a specific Intent). That is all possible with an `IntentServie` but when I send that 'stop' `Intent` it needs to be processed as the next item in the queue, not the last where it is right now.

EDIT

For those interested I have taken the AOSP code for `IntentService` and modified it to meet my needs. The reason I cannot just subclass IntentHandler is because of the private `ServiceHandler` class inside of `IntentHandler`.

Inside of the `ServiceHandler` I have a new method:

```
 public final boolean sendPriorityMessage(Message msg)
        {
            int priority = msg.arg2;
            //Log.i(GenericList.TAG,"recieved message priority: "+priority);


            if(priority>PRIORITY_NORMAL){
                return sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(msg);
            }else{
                return sendMessage(msg);    
            }

        }
```

This method is called from `onStart` instead of just `sendMessage`

```
 @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        msg.obj = intent;
        try{
            msg.arg2 = intent.getExtras().getInt(KEY_PRIORITY);
        }catch(Exception e){
            msg.arg2 = PRIORITY_NORMAL;
        }

        mServiceHandler.sendPriorityMessage(msg);
    }
```

Overall the code is still limited but I am able to fast track some messages to the front of the queue, which is what I was after anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could implement/extend your own PriorityQueue that simply checks every new intent added to the queue. if it's the stop intent, it moves it straight to the front of the line.

Comment: The PriorityQueue by itself is just the data structure though, What I need is IntentService that uses a PriorityQueue to store pending intents. It might be possible if I were to subclass and override the corresponding methods. Time to dig though some of Android's source code...